# Mounting a PCB in an Extruded Aluminum case

Tags: cases, mount

I want to make a case for a PCB using extruded aluminum. (Such as the IPOD nano shown below, and the portable amp under it).

1. How do I mount the PCB inside the alumimum extrusion? (I know some come with slots but are there different options?
2. Who are some good suppliers of extruded aluminum? (bonus if they do milling on small quantities too)

[image: Example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For extruded aluminum, find the local distributor for aluminum structural framing in your area. Try 8020.net in the US and Bosch-Rexroth in Europe. You might also try [frontpanelexpress.com](http://www.frontpanelexpress.com), though their stuff might be too big.

Here are some options to mount the PCB:

1. The slots
2. [PEM studs](http://www.pemnet.com/fastening_products/prod_desc.php3?cat=Fasteners+for+PC+Boards) (you'd need a fabricator to press these in for you)
3. Bolts and standoffs (try Digikey)

For the PEM studs, check out the KSSB family-- they're designed specially for mounting PCBs without extra fasteners.

Comment: Would ["Fasteners For Mounting Into Printed Circuit Boards"](http://www.pemnet.com/fastening_products/circuit_board.html) make a good replacement for that dead link to PEM studs?