# How can I design my PCB to mount to a wood panel without wasting a lot of space on screw holes?

Tags: pcb-design, mount

I'm designing a small board, with [these quick disconnect](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/4966/4966K-ND/303924) tabs along the edges.  The board will be mounted to a non-conductive surface.  I had initially planned to use screws at the corners, but the shape of the components means this results in a significant increase of footprint, and I'd like to keep costs down.  My hope is to avoid margins, such as those in [this (trivial) example](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9966).

Is there a more efficient way to mount this board, in terms of board area?  I've considered soldering on ring connectors that will stick out the corners, and putting screws through the rings.  That seems weak and
unprofessional, though.  Slot mounting is unfavorable, since the board will be mounted on a flat surface with space around it.

Related questions:
[Mounting a PCB in an Extruded Aluminum case](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/mounting-a-pcb-in-an-extruded-aluminum-case)
[Mounting my PCB project](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8319/mounting-my-pcb-project)

Comment: You can cut dadoes in the wood -- i.e., slots to hold your board, if its box-shaped.

Comment: That's a really good idea; I may do that

Comment: Here's another related thread: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/106487/7036

Comment: Not quite my idea-- there are many plastic enclosures with slots in the side to do just this.

Comment: Thank @NickAlexeev, I missed that question in my initial search.  I'll consider adhesives as a possible solution.

Comment: If this is wire to board with large force connect/disconnects, you want rugged and small and prevent solder cracks from stress with protruding solder tabs below board, I might consider tiny alignment fasteners and rigid polyurethane adhesive dabbed below stress points on quick disconnects.  Hardware stored has large tubes of PU subfloor adhesive to do this permanent job.

Comment: Another possibility is to sandwich the board between two pieces of conductive foam, then apply pressure to hold it in place. If heat becomes an issue, cut holes in the upper layer of foam over each hot component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on board size and layout, you could mount it with 1 or 2 screws in the middle portion of the board rather than 4 screws at the corners. I've seen several devices that either aren't bothered by a small misalignment, or that use 1-2 screws plus pegs to achieve tight alignment without adding much to the footprint.

Comment: I think this approach will work the best.  I've experimented with some layout options, and there may be room near the middle for screw holes.  Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://oshpark.com/shared_projects/gtwkWu6U) wound up being the final design.